# Git: Same line edit: Who has Precedence?

Tags: git

If I have two branches, "product" and "staging" and in both branches I change this line:

```
private baseUrl = "someDomain";
```

I now notice that this results in

1) auto-forward and not a merge conflict
2) latest commit seem to have precedence
3) it does not matter from which branch I do the merge

Can anybody confirm and explain these findings?

Comment: It's hard to answer without an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: There's definitely information missing here, and I'm not sure about the terms you're using. Do you mean that when you merge it performs a fast-forward? That would imply that whatever change you made to the file in the "older" branch is already in the history of the "newer" branch, so of course the more recent change takes precedence in that situation. If you can provide enough information to clarify if that's what happening, then I could write up a more detailed explanation as an answer

Comment: I'm guessing a bit, but I think you are asking the same question as the one I chose as duplicate.